# Condition s.t. all closed set with dimension d in $\mathbb P^n$ intersects a closed set X

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there a condition makes all closed set with dimension d in $\mathbb P^n$ intersect a closed subset X.

I know it is true that any d-dimensional closed set intersects every n-d dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb P^n$. So I wonder does there exist similar theorem.

I am guessing maybe the condition is that X contains a linear n-d dimensional subspace. Is it true?

Comment: See Theorem I.7.2 of Hartshorne. Of course Daniel's proof below is correct but my guess is that you're not "ready" for Chow rings just yet.

Comment: @Hoot. You are absolutely right : a pleasantly  elementary reference indeed.

Comment: I don't know what Theorem 1.7.2 of Hartshorne says, but this is just the fact that to eat up all of the irrelevant ideal you need the sum of the heights to be $n+1$.

Comment: @Hoot I will check that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two closed sets $X,Y$ in projective $n$-space intersect if  $\dim X+\dim Y\geq n$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have two disjoint subvarieties $X, Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$, say with $\dim X = p$ and $\dim Y = q$.  Then in the Chow ring
$$A^\ast(\mathbb{P}^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]/(\zeta^{n+1}),$$
where $\zeta$ is the class of a hyperplane, we have $[X] \cdot [Y] = 0$, since an empty intersection is transverse.  (For an introduction to the Chow ring that covers everything used here, see *3264 and All That* by Eisenbud and Harris, which is available online from the authors.)  On the other hand, we know that
$$[X] = d \, \zeta^{n-p} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad [Y] = e \, \zeta^{n-q},$$
where $d$ and $e$ are the degrees of $X$ and $Y$, so
$$0 = [X] \cdot [Y] = d \, e \, \zeta^{2n - p - q}.$$
Since $d, e \neq 0$, it follows that $\zeta^{2n - p - q}=0$, i.e. that
$$2n - p - q \geq n+1.$$
Solving,
$$p + q \leq n-1.$$
So it follows that if $\dim X + \dim Y \geq n$ then $X$ and $Y$ must intersect.

Comment: Congratulations Daniel : very didactic and crystal-clear explanation, with  not one comma to add or subtract !

Comment: Well, not quite: I re-read it just now and realized I was missing an "=0."